# Add custom property with RIA Service on client side

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I need to add a custom attribute on client side with WCF RIA Service. This property isn't in my Model (.edmx) but is an implementation of my interface.

The property to add:

```
public IEmployee MyEmployee
{
   get { }
}
```

I try this:

```
[DataMemberAttribute]
public IEmployee MyEmployee
{
   get { }
}
```

but this doesn't work.

A basic return type works:

```
[DataMemberAttribute]
public string MyEmployeeId
{
   get { }
}
```

(I think) it's because I return an IEmployee and I need to implement this property.

I can't rename the file to *.shared.cs due to his dependencies.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: What dependencies are these? Can you share IEmployee with the client?

Comment: I could share IEmployee but in this interface there are others interfaces (with dependencies too...) that I can not share on client side.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reasone you just need the property on the client, keep in mind that entities created on the client-side are `partial` classes, so I guess you could extend them and add the properties you need.
Hope it helps.